# View SQL Queries/times for page request

Tags: sql, query

SharePoint 2010 has the fancy new developer dashboard where you can view the SQL queries made and how long they took to determine bottlenecks etc.

I am not a SQL Sysadmin so I cannot use SQL profiler (plus there is so much load it would be difficult to filter).

Is there a way of viewing this information using SharePoint 2007 (e.g. an API method, class, web part)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using SQL Profiler, and using very specifically crafted filters - we actually created them by testing on a dev box.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is a 2010 enhancement and no equivalent exists in 2007